# Asynchronously loading a javascript component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is a snippet of the js code of the current page.

```
$('.addon-oauth').each(function(index, elem) {

    var viewModel = new addonSettings.OAuthAddonSettingsViewModel(
        $(elem).data('addon-short-name'),
        $(elem).data('addon-name')
    );
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, elem);
    viewModel.updateAccounts();
});
```

and inside the "updateAccounts()" method of another js file are

```
updateAccounts: function() {
    var self = this;
    var url = '/api/v1/settings/' + self.name + '/accounts/';
    var request = $.get(url);
    request.done(function(data) {
        self.accounts($.map(data.accounts, function(account) {
            return new ExternalAccount(account);
        }));
        $('#' + self.name + '-header').osfToggleHeight({height: 140});
    });
    request.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        Raven.captureMessage('Error while updating addon account', {
            extra: {
                url: url,
                status: status,
                error: error
            }
        });
    });
    return request;
}
```

and "osfToggleHeight" is a js component to hide/collapse long list of elements like this
[image]
However it doesn't always work. Sometimes only some lists would be hidden/collapsed, e.g
[image]
The list for google drive is collapsed correctly, but not the list for Mendeley.
I suspect the reason is that the page finished loading before all async requests are returned. Any ideas on how to fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: Please help us reproduce the problem by providing an [mcve]. There are quite a few bits missing for us to be able to help you (most notably some context, `self.accounts`, and the corresponding view code).

Comment: At any rate, some of your problems will very likely stem from the fact that you're not really *using* knockoutjs: I recommend strongly against modifying the DOM like that from your view models. Modify only the view models, and handle DOM interaction for plugins and so on using [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).